# (eosio v2.0.2) contract prints are not shown, even using nodeos with --contracts-console parameter

Tags: eosio-code

simple contract compiled using eosio.cdt v1.7.0:

```c
#include <eosiolib/contracts/eosio/eosio.hpp>
#include <eosiolib/core/eosio/print.hpp>

using namespace eosio;

CONTRACT eventhandler : public eosio::contract {

    public:
        using contract::contract;

        ACTION test() {
            print("HELLO WORLD\n");
        }
};

EOSIO_DISPATCH ( eventhandler, (test) )
```

line to run nodeos:

```
nodeos -e -p eosio --contracts-console --plugin eosio::producer_plugin --plugin eosio::chain_api_plugin --plugin eosio::http_plugin --plugin eosio::history_api_plugin -d /var/www/blockchain/eosio/data --config-dir /var/www/blockchain/eosio/config --access-control-allow-origin=* --http-validate-host=false
```

If I use **eosio 1.5.7** or lower, the following push...

```
cleos push action eventhandler test '[]' -p eventhandler
```

...will generate an output in the console like this:

```
info  2020-02-10T23:30:54.001 thread-0  producer_plugin.cpp:1556      produce_block        ] Produced block 000000295902c4b5... #41 @ 2020-02-10T23:30:54.000 signed by eosio [trxs: 24, lib: 40, confirmed: 0]
debug 2020-02-10T23:30:54.008 thread-0  apply_context.cpp:28          print_debug          ] 
[(eventhandler,test)->eventhandler]: CONSOLE OUTPUT BEGIN =====================
HELLO WORLD
[(eventhandler,test)->eventhandler]: CONSOLE OUTPUT END   =====================
info  2020-02-10T23:30:55.000 thread-0  producer_plugin.cpp:1556      produce_block        ] Produced block 0000002b9c5bcd55... #42 @ 2020-02-10T23:30:55.000 signed by eosio [trxs: 23, lib: 42, confirmed: 0]
```

but if I uninstall this eosio version and install **eosio v2.0.2**, then I execute the same thing but nothing gets printed in the console (apart from the blocks counting)

```
info  2020-02-10T23:30:57.000 thread-0  producer_plugin.cpp:1556      produce_block        ] Produced block 0000002fa118b688... #47 @ 2020-02-10T23:30:57.000 signed by eosio [trxs: 0, lib: 46, confirmed: 0]
info  2020-02-10T23:30:57.501 thread-0  producer_plugin.cpp:1556      produce_block        ] Produced block 000000300d4de245... #48 @ 2020-02-10T23:30:57.500 signed by eosio [trxs: 0, lib: 47, confirmed: 0]
info  2020-02-10T23:30:58.000 thread-0  producer_plugin.cpp:1556      produce_block        ] Produced block 00000031eff776de... #49 @ 2020-02-10T23:30:58.000 signed by eosio [trxs: 0, lib: 48, confirmed: 0]
info  2020-02-10T23:30:58.501 thread-0  producer_plugin.cpp:1556      produce_block        ] Produced block 0000003228c75c64... #50 @ 2020-02-10T23:30:58.500 signed by eosio [trxs: 0, lib: 49, confirmed: 0]
```

**QUESTIONS:**
Am I missing something?
is this output printed somewhere else?
maybe a log file?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? i'm experiencing the same issue. i added a logging.json and set the --config-dir path to the folder and its still not showing anything in nodeos.log

Answer (score 3):

Contract console out in nodeos log is `debug` level, but default logging level of nodeos is changed from `debug` to `info`. If you want to print console out, put next logging.json in your config directory.

```
{
  "includes": [],
  "appenders": [{
      "name": "stderr",
      "type": "console",
      "args": {
        "stream": "std_error",
        "level_colors": [{
            "level": "debug",
            "color": "green"
          },{
            "level": "warn",
            "color": "brown"
          },{
            "level": "error",
            "color": "red"
          }
        ]
      },
      "enabled": true
    },{
      "name": "stdout",
      "type": "console",
      "args": {
        "stream": "std_out",
        "level_colors": [{
            "level": "debug",
            "color": "green"
          },{
            "level": "warn",
            "color": "brown"
          },{
            "level": "error",
            "color": "red"
          }
        ]
      },
      "enabled": true
    }
  ],
  "loggers": [{
      "name": "default",
      "level": "debug",
      "enabled": true,
      "additivity": false,
      "appenders": [
        "stderr"
      ]
    },{
      "name": "net_plugin_impl",
      "level": "info",
      "enabled": true,
      "additivity": false,
      "appenders": [
        "stderr"
      ]
    },{
      "name": "http_plugin",
      "level": "info",
      "enabled": true,
      "additivity": false,
      "appenders": [
        "stderr"
      ]
    },{
      "name": "producer_plugin",
      "level": "info",
      "enabled": true,
      "additivity": false,
      "appenders": [
        "stderr"
      ]
    },{
      "name": "transaction_tracing",
      "level": "info",
      "enabled": true,
      "additivity": false,
      "appenders": [
        "stderr"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: awesome @conr2d, thx!

Comment: @cmadh My pleasure :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why this happens, but I've also been struggling with it.

I get around it by doing

```
eosio::print("hello!");
eosio::check(false, "uh oh");
```

So when I do `cleos push action ...` it then errors out the transaction, but prints "hello!" in the console.

Would also love to know a better way to print, but for now maybe this could help!